# VSCode custom 'Fix' option, applying linter rules

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

My project linting rules exist of:

- imports ordering (On top of alphabetically)
- CSS ordering.

These are forced using linter, and I was wondering how to apply rules automatically, so VSCode **fix** option, would know to organize code by my custom needs.

[image]

How can I archive this? VSCode extensions documentary does not exist of code formatting...

If you have a better option for the achieve this, it would also be accepted as an answer (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not finding anything because "fix" is not a VSC construct, it's an extension construct.

So whether fixes or those actions are implemented automatically or not depend on the extension, not on VSC. You won't find anything like that on VSC's settings. You *may* find that on the extension's settings, *if the authors choose to provide those*.

Luckily for you, ESLint [offers an `eslint.autoFixOnSave` option](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint), which is probablly what you're looking for.

Likewise, TSLint [offers an `tslint.autoFixOnSave` option](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint).

In both cases, they follow the linting rules configured by their respective configuration files (`eslintrc`, `tslint.json`, etc), so as long as you have your rules declared there, they'd follow your "custom needs".

In general, when using a VSC extension, be sure to check the extension's info page. They tend to list the additional settings they add to the editor there.